# How does increase in volume change the speed of reaction in production of NO2?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

$$\ce{2 NO + O2 <=> 2 NO2}$$

I understand that increasing the volume $×2$ means lower pressure so production of $\ce{NO2}$ is slowed down, but when asked how to express this mathematicaly I can't get to the correct value, which is either $4$ or $8.$ I don't see how inserting $1/2$ in $v = Δc/(2×Δt)$ can give anything close to the offered solutions.

Comment: The reaction rate isn't necessarily proportional to the concentration in reactants: it depends on the order of the reaction.

Comment: @ThomasJungers Yes, but concentration is the only value I can change with the increase of volume. I tried placing 2V in the formula for the constant of the reaction k=([NO2]^2)/([NO]^2×[O2]) but i got different results for every option I tried and non of them are 4 nor 8

Comment: Your $k$ is an equilibrium constant. That is entirely different from the kinetics of the reaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not an expert but this is how I would do it.

- Determine the reaction rate formula from the reaction equation

  $$r = K[\ce{NO}]^2[\ce{O2}]$$
- Changing the volume by a factor $2$ means the concentration of $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{O2}$ will become half

  $$r' = K\cdot\frac{[\ce{NO}]}{2}^2\cdot\frac{[\ce{O2}]}{2}$$
- Compare the reaction rates

  $$r' = K[\ce{NO}]^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot [\ce{O2}]\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

  $$\frac{r}{r'} = \frac{K[\ce{NO}]^2[\ce{O2}]}{K[\ce{NO}]^2[\ce{O2}]\cdot\frac{1}{8}} = 8$$

Conclusion: increasing the volume by $2$ will decrease the concentration (or pressure) of $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{O2}.$ This causes the reaction rate to decrease by a factor of $8$.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. Briefly, one can use `\ce{…}` for chemical formulas and `$$…$$` instead of `$\displaystyle …$`. `\displaystyle` is pretty much only useful for the inline mode.

Comment: The partial orders in the rate law are equal to the stoichiometric coefficients of a reaction _only_ when that reaction is an elementary reaction. I sincerely doubt that $\ce{2 NO + O2 <=> 2 NO2}$ is an elementary reaction.
As it happens, the rate law for this reaction is indeed $r = k [\ce{NO}]^2 [\ce{O2}]$, but it is a coincidence.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Thomas I agree with you on that. It's impossible for the reaction to be elementary because the reactant contains 3 molecules, I didn't think about that. I searched for the reaction mechanism on google and this: https://resources.saylor.org/wwwresources/archived/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/CHEM102-1.4-Reaction-Mechanisms.pdf page 6 suggested that it's a two step reaction forming an intermediate N2O2. And it happens to match the observed rate law.